# How to identify camera app?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, camera, stock-android

Is there a way to identify the stock camera app on an android device? Browsing the installed packages using Titanium Backup didn't show any package with "camera" in its name.

With the app identified, i hope to find some info or documentation regarding the app's features.

EDIT:

To be more precise - i'm trying to detect the name of the camera app that came with the device. I own a Galaxy Tab 3 and a Fairphone - the camera apps on both devices differ regarding functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The camera and gallery apps are the same on Android 4.3 and below.

It got separated only on KitKat version.

So you have to look for gallery apk on titanium backup. Probably named Gallery 4.apk or Gallery 2.apk with com.android.gallery3d....as its package name

Comment: I think by "stock", the submitter means the name of the camera package that came with the phone (which likely is not google's app). Most devices come with their own flavor of a camera app, each with its own features and under its own package name.

Comment: Exactly - i'm trying to detect the name of the camera app that came with the device - i've edited my question. But thanks a lot @AlexanderTheGreat for a first answer!